# String replacement but only for the substring within quotes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a situation where the given string is

`hello,"sai,sur",ya,teja`

and the expected output from the given string is

`hello,sai-sur,ya,teja`

Comma between quotation has to be replace with `-` character and the rest of the string should be as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the string within quotes using `"([^"]+)"` ([Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yCMsDr/1)). This will get the string without the quotes to a capturing group. Then, replace all the `,` with `-` in the matched string.

The second parameter to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) is function, The first parameter of this *replacer* function is the entire matched substring, including the quotes. The second parameter is the capturing group. Since you want to to remove the `"` from the output, you can directly use the capturing group parameter.

```js
const input = `hello,"sai,sur",ya,teja`,
      output = input.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, (_, g) => g.replace(',', '-'))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: What if the string has odd number of quotation marks? Like `"hello,"sai,sur",ya,teja`

Comment: @SaiSurya it will only replace commas within matching `""`. So, the `,` after hello will be replaced with a `-`. The `"` after `sur` will be kept as it is. Please check the regex demo in the answer to test out scenarios.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mark. I want to remove the last occurrence of  character `"` in the string if there are odd number of quotation marks in the given string can you help me with that please?

Comment: @SaiSurya so, you want to remove every `"` in the output string?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to match all quoted terms and then use a callback function to replace commas with dash:

```js
var input = "hello,\"sai,sur\",ya,teja";
var output = input.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, (match, startIndex, wholeString) => {
    return match.replace(",", "-");
});
console.log("input:  " + input);
console.log("output: " + output);
```

Comment: What if the string has odd number of quotation marks? Like `"hello,"sai,sur",ya,teja`

Comment: Then my answer might not work, but then again, you would need to articulate rules for which of those three quotes are the "real" ones.  Note that now your input can be read in two ways.  One, the quoted term is `"hello,"`, two the term is `"sai,sur"`

Comment: Hi I want to remove the last occurrence of  character `"` in the string if there are odd number of quotation marks in the given string can you help me with that please?

Comment: I can't help here, but that sounds like a great follow up question.

Comment: Here is the link for the follow up question please have a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458132/string-manipulation-to-remove-last-occurrence-of-a-character-typescript-or
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const result = 'hello,"sai,sur",ya,teja'.replace(/(.*)"(.*)(,)(.*)"(.*)/,  '$1$2-$4$5')

console.log(result)
```

The keyword of this technique is "Regex group replace"